# How do you edit a row in an angular dialog window and have the current information appear?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a table that I want to edit using Angular. When the user clicks the edit button, a dialog window pops up that is the same as the add entry dialog window. However, when the fields are still blank. I would like the input fields to be populated with the current information for that entry that can be edited. How is this done?

````
    onEdit() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "475px";
    this.dialog.open(ApplicationEditComponent, dialogConfig);
  }




    ```EditList.ts
        applicationForm = this.fb.group({
       appName: ['', Validators.required],
       appCode: ['', Validators.required]
     })




```EditList.html

    <form [formGroup]="applicationForm" class="form">

     <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="startcenter">

     <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="App Code:" type="text"    formControlName="appCode" required autofocus>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Application Name:" type="text"  formControlName="appName" required autofocus>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>


```ListServices.ts

     updateApplication(application: IApplicationData) {
    return this.http.put<IApplicationData>(this.myAppUrl + 'api/Application/Edit', application)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
````

Comment: do you want to pass data from form to the popup?

Comment: @FaizalHussain yes, I do. It is coming from a table on a form

Answer (score 0):

Data can be passed to material dialog, like -

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(YourDialog, {
  data: { name: 'austin' },
});
```

and then it can be accessed from dialog component -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-dialog',
  template: 'passed in {{ data.name }}',
})
export class YourDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

so the row to be edited can be passed to the edit dialog and used in there

For details please refer - 
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-

Answer (score 0):

just add data property

```
   onEdit() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "475px";
    this.dialog.open(ApplicationEditComponent, dialogConfig , data: {
    data: this.applicationForm.value
  });
  }
```

To receive the data in ApplicationEditComponent.ts

```
 constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
receiveddata :any;

ngOnInit(){
this.receiveddata = this.data;
}
```